# How do we pull text columns basis on the dates using filter formula in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a sample table in the sheet where I want yearly, or if required monthly active clients which are recurring until they are lost and will be counted for each period until it gets lost.

I want to populate this using a filter formula or any other formula that might help solve the query in google sheets.

Attaching the sample spreadsheet to where the yellow area is the desired outcome.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VIRp18HJyJ2UdfaHhaCpCHpfO6ctHW29TtP4iFJwYiU/edit#gid=0

I tried filter formula, for example for the year 2022

```
= filter(<Col a>, <colb>="<=2022-12-31",<Col D>="Live")
```

which did not work  and do not know the logic of where we will need it for the year 2021

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,map(B2:B,C2:C,D2:D,lambda(b,c,d,if(or(b="",d="Inactive"),,year(if(c="-",now(),c))-year(b)+1))),
     Δ,{tocol(map(A2:A,Σ,lambda(a,z,if(a="",,wraprows(a,z,a)))),3),tocol(map(B2:B,Σ,lambda(b,z,if(b="",,sequence(1,z,year(b),1)))),3)},
       bycol(torow(unique(index(Δ,,2))),lambda(z,{z;filter(index(Δ,,1),index(Δ,,2)=z)})))
```

[image]